Handling concurrency race in sqlalchemy
I don't understand how to avoid concurrency when there are more sessions.
Let's imagine there are some table User:
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    email: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(unique=True)
    hashed_password: Mapped[str]

crud functions:
async def create(db: AsyncSession, user_scheme: UserCreate) -> User:
    user = User(
        **user_scheme.model_dump(exclude={"password"}),
        hashed_password=hash_password(user_scheme.password),
    )
    db.add(user)
    await db.commit()
    return user


async def exists_by_email(db: AsyncSession, user_email: str) -> bool:
    stmt = sql.select(sql.exists(User).where(User.email == user_email))
    res = await db.scalar(stmt)
    return bool(res)

and route function:
@router.post("/", status_code=201, response_model=UserRead)
async def register_user(db: SessionDepends, user_scheme: UserCreate) -> User:
    # step 1: check if is email taken
    if await crud.user.exists_by_email(db, user_scheme.email):
        raise HTTPException(409, "Email is already taken")
    
    # step 2: create and return user
    return await crud.user.create(db, user_scheme)

What if there are two clients that trying to register user with a same email and occur situations like below:



Session 1
Session 2




Check if the email is taken -> False




Check if the email is taken -> False


Create user -> user




Create user -> exception


Return -> 201 user
Return -> 500 :(



I want to learn how to properly write code in these cases?

Since you haven't defined your email field as unique, I'm not sure if this going to error out in either case - but the common solution is to define your email field as unique in the database (i.e. have a constraint that says email needs to be unique), and you handle that exception when committing your session - telling the user that the email address isn't available. Trying to add it and handling the error from the database layer is the only real way of avoiding a race condition (or you can implement locking yourself, but you'll be doing the same thing as what your RDBMS does for you).

I forgot to add unique to email in example, thanks for solution
